# Simple Dash App runs on localhost but will not run on Microsoft Azure Web App

Tags: python, azure

I am using the latest version of VSCode and have written the simplest of dash apps:

```
'''   
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
dcc.Markdown(''' ### Ayup python world ''')
])
if __name__ == '__main__'
    app.run_server()
'''
```

This runs on my localhost without issue.

I have a folder on my desktop named "practice" and I used "python -m venv venv" to set up a virtual environment. I then activated the venv using "venv\Scripts\activate", downloaded dash using "pip install dash" and generated a requirements.txt file "pip freeze > requirements.txt".

folder structure:

```
'''
practice:
>venv
app.py
requirements.txt
'''
```

To learn how to use Microsoft Azure I set-up a free trail acount and also installed Docker on my laptop.

I then installed the Azure and Docker extensions in VScode and then generated an image of my app using Docker:

CTRL-SHIFT P
Docker Images: Build Image...

Couldn't find a Dockerfile in your workspace. Would you like to add Docker files to the workspace? 
Python General
Enter a Python module instead - app.py
include optional Docker Compose files? - No

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
'''
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "-m", "app.py"]
'''
```

New folder structure
'''
practice:
>venv
>.vscode
.dockerignore
app.py
Dockerfile
requirements.text
'''
After running Docker Images the app ran on my localhost with no issues.

I then went to my Azure subscription and setup a container registry, a resource group and an App service:

Create a resource
Container Registry - Create
Subscription - Azure subscription 1
Resource group - Create new - mick-practice-resource-group
Registry name - mickPracticeRegistry
Location - Canada Central
Pricing plan - Basic
Review and Create - Validation passed
Create - Deployment succeeded

App Services
Create - Web App
Subscription - Azure subscription 1
Resource group - Create new - mick-practice-resource-group
Name - mickPracticeApp
Publish - Docker Container
Operating System - Linux
Location - Canada Central
Linux plan - (New) ASP-mickpracticeresorucegroup-809e
Pricing plan - Free F1 (Shared infrastructure)
Zone redundancy - Disabled
Review and Create
Create - Your deployment is complete

I then went back to VSCode to the Docker extension:
under Images
Right Click on Practice:latest
Push - mickpracticeregistry.azurecr.io/practice:latest
Push successful

App opened on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ without issue

In Docker went to Registries, clicked connect icon and connected.
clicked refresh and practice folder appeared
dropdown revealed latest
right clicked on latest and selected Deploy Image to Azure App Service...
Name: mickPracticeWebApp
Resource group: mick-practice-resource-group
Service plan: ASP-mickpracticeresorucegroup-809e

Successfully created web app "mickPracticeWebApp"
https://mickpracticewebapp.azurewebsites.net

Clicked Open Site

Do you want Code to open external website?
Open

New window opens with Loading and circling ellipse until ":( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources."

I have spent a couple of days trying to understand what's happening to no avail. I think this has something to do with the app.run_server() line. I have also tried with app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port='8050) and app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port='80).

It's driving me crazy. Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce your requirement in my environment with the same code and got `Application Error` while accessing the deployed application.***

### [image]

**Resolution:**

Follow the below steps to resolve the error:

- Add the **port bindings** in the code as shown below:

```py
import os
from dash import Dash, dcc, html

app = Dash(__name__)
server = app.server
app.layout = html.Div([
dcc.Markdown(''' ### python world ''')
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port='8000')
```

- Add Startup command `python <filename>.py` in `App Service=>Settings=>Configuration=>General Settings=> Startup Command`:

[image]

**Run the application:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I found that adding app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8050))) to the bottom of the code also works.